# jenkinsfile multi environment

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multi environment build: a Qt application that I build on mac, linux and windows.
I'm using a "Multi-Configuration Projects" so far to build on my 3 slaves and have the 3 artifacts on the master jenkins.

Now I'd like to do the same with Jenkinsfile. How can I proceed?

Here is the experiment I did (not my real project, but it's a simplified sample)

```
stage 'clone'
node {
     git url: 'https://github.com/Foo/test.git'
     stash "source"
}

stage 'build'
parallel "random-string-1": {
    node("linux") {
      unstash "source"
      sh "./build.sh linux"
      echo "it was linux"
      stash "arch"
    }
}, "random-string-2": {
    node("mac") {
      unstash "source"
      sh "./build.sh mac"
      echo "it was mac"
      stash "arch"
    }
}

stage 'archive'
node {
     unstash "arch"
     archive "test"
}
```

When I do that, I have only one artefact on the master.

Any idea of the syntax I should use?

Comment: looks at first glance like the second of your two calls to stash "arch" is going to overwrite the first. So if the mac build is faster, the linux build will overwrite it. Maybe try giving the artifacts different names and unstashing them separately?